# create new variable using assign variable

Tags: r, concatenation, cat

I want to create a new variable using assign variable value in r just like a macro using in SAS.

```
For example:-

ID<-"RC090015"

my_ID_code<-xyz 

It should be written as my_RC090015_code<-xyz.
```

so my requirement is i want to use ID variable for creating new variable for code generalization purpose. Means suppose i just change the ID variable value so it should be change in all further variable where i used ID variable.

So please help me is there any function in r to include that ID variable for creating new variable including ID value.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `assign`

```
assign(paste("my", ID, "code", sep="_"), xyz)
my_RC090015_code
#[1] 24
```

#### Update

It should work also for the subset datasets

```
assign(paste("my",ID,"code",sep="_"), 
           SUBSET_DATA_MAIN[Terminal_ID==ID])

my_RC090015_code
#   Terminal_ID val
#1:    RC090015  24
#2:    RC090015  22
```

#### data

```
xyz <- 24
library(data.table)
SUBSET_DATA_MAIN <- data.table(Terminal_ID= c("RC090015",
       "RC090017", "RC090015"), val= c(24, 23, 22))
```

Comment: But there is one problem.when i run this query..  paste0(paste("my",ID,"code",sep="_"))<-SUBSET_DATA_MAIN[Terminal_ID==ID] but it gives error. i want to store subset data in to new variable like my_RC090015_code.

Comment: ERROR:-                                                                                                     Error in paste0(paste("my", ID, "code", sep = "_")) <- SUBSET_DATA_MAIN[Terminal_ID ==  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'symbol'

Comment: @Shahnawaz  You cannot use `paste` to assign (`<`).  It is not what I suggested.  I used `assign`

Comment: I also tried using assign function but data not stored in new variable. assign (paste0(paste("my",ID,"code",sep="_")),SUBSET_DATA_MAIN[Terminal_ID==ID])

Comment: @Shahnawaz Without knowing what the `SUBSET_DATA_MAIN` and also it seems like you are subsetting columns instead of rows, it is difficult to suggest.

Comment: SUBSET_DATA_MAIN is a data.table contains 40k records and 13 columns .i want to subset data with id wise and store data into new data table which names contain ID value.

Comment: @Shahnawaz  I created a reproducible example and it is working for me.